# Bindning свойства IsEnabled TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Необходимо запретить редактирование TextBox, если Text="Администратор". Сделал через триггер, однако при таком варианте если пользователь вручную вводит администратор, TextBox также становится неактивным. Как можно это реализовать. Конечно всегда есть вариант написать в коде, но коль уж мы имеем дело с wpf хотелось бы сделать через него.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. Вы хотите, чтобы учитывалось только _начальное_ значение поля `Text`? А как оно там появляется, не через XAML?

Comment: Да, именно это я и хочу. Появляется оно через XAML, то есть через привязку данных.

Comment: А что делать, если строка, к которой привязан текст, изначально не "Администратор", но изменится на "Администратор" позже?

Comment: Тогда ничего не должно происходить, в дальнейшем уже проверяется на существование такой записи. Ладно, может оно и не стоит того. Просто учусь в рамках wpf мыслить декларативно.

Comment: @Serega Isupov, имхо, на самом деле, чем проще, тем лучше. Потом при поддержке или передаче проекта запаритесь объяснять что, зачем и почему сделано, если будут выверты.

Comment: @Макс: считайте это экстремальным упражнением в программировании с препятствиями. На [Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/) тоже приходит код, не рекомендуемый к выдаче заказчикам.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вам решение на XAML. Надеюсь, я правильно понял, что вы хотите:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" Value="Admin">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Спасибо, только боюсь, что уже не смогу проверить работу. :)

Comment: @IsM: Почему? Вы больше не программируете или ушли с платформы WPF?

Comment: Тот проект уже канул в лету

Comment: @IsM: Ну, проверить-то легко: создаёте пустой проект, в code-behind пишете [вот это](http://pastebin.com/Tj2gGz1V), запускаете. Меняете `Text = "Admin";` на что-то другое, снова запускаете.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, я не совсем понял задачу, но что мешает в конструкторе формы сделать проверку

```
if(tbx.Text.Equals("Администратор"))
   tbx.Enabled = false;
```

?

Comment: В том то и дело, я же написал, что ничего не мешает сделать это в коде, но хотелось бы реализовать этот средствами XAML

Answer (score 0):

Если ты используешь MVVM-Pattern, то можно сделать привязку IsEnabeld к Property в ViewModel и во время изменения текста (TextChange event) проверять его и соответственно реагировать как хочется. 
В принципе аналогичное поведение можно и без использования этого шаблона сделать...

Comment: Автор хочет через XAML, с code-behind любой сможет.

Comment: ViewModel это не Code-Behind :) Прям совсем-совсем через XAML? Думаю, что оно того не стоит.

Comment: Не придирайтесь к словам :-) Совсем-совсем через XAML, иначе всё самоочевидно.